# X-API-KEY headers autentication Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http-headers

I currently working on the project which is API centred application. The restapi is build on code igniter in php. This part works great, I am able to receive data using postman plugin and authenticate with API key.

I know how to receive or post data with angular, but I have no idea how to start with authentication.

I cant find much information on the internet related to X-API-KEY that's reason why I asking this question here. For the front-end I am going to use angularjs. I don't know even when to start. The question is:

How to authenticate with headers using angularjs. I would really appreciate if someone could point me to some resources so I can do some reading.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a default header during your module's **run** function and later check it on the server.

```js
module.run(function($http) {
  $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic YmVlcDpib29w'
});
```

You can also check the documentation for the **$http** service in angular [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).